# listening port not showing port no 15672 rabbiMQ

Tags: http, rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ in Cent OS server .Under `ipaddress:15671`
in `portno` and `contextr` section its not showing http 15672 port. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you enabled the RabbitMQ management plugin?  - https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: yes i have enabled by usinf this cmd:  sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server.service

Comment: That doesn't enable the management plugin - see the command in the page I linked above